# Reference guide for standard descriptions of materials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, material-science

Is there any reference that has a coherent list of materials and what type of approximate Hamiltonian to best describe them with (where it is known). Particularily I am looking for the following bits of information in an organized form

- A list of materials that are described by tight binding parameters and good parameters
- A list of materials that are well described by a Hubbard model with parameters
- A list of materials described well by the Heisenberg model with parameters
- Lists of other types of materials possibly with a listing of parameters

Comment: The question is very broad in its scope, so I doubt if there is actually a publication that attempts to give a summary as you suggested. Also, sometimes a Hubbard model can be mapped into Heisenberg spin model (e.g. http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/5/1/113/meta).

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to ask for experts (which I am not) to provide a PARADIGMATIC example for each of the models.

Comment: Hm. Cannot add book banner. Bug?

Comment: Here is a paper that has a promising abstract (https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1640). It seems to be aimed for new students and it reviews four effective Hamiltonians in wide use within solid state physics today: tight binding, Hubbard, Heisenberg, and Holstein hamiltonians. I only skimmed through figures but I can see it mentions several example materials (includes organic compounds) for each effective Hamiltonian. Hopefully someone can review this paper in an official answer.

Comment: I know that there is a lot of information out there for many different systems but from the lack of answers I can guess that the information is only available in the scattered format I am aware of. I was hoping for an organization repository of information like there exists with matrial constants etc.